# how to insert int value from a textbox to field in database that is in integer type?

Tags: asp.net

I have a textbox in front view in asp.net windows form and a integer field in database  i.e transaction name and transaction id .Now when I insert transaction name in the transaction box,in the backend it should generate transaction id.

Comment: can anybody give me the code plz

Comment: In order to get help on this site, you really need to post what you've tried already, or narrow your question down to something more specific. Don't just ask us to provide all the code you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE transaction ( transactionid int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,transactionname varchar(MAX) NOT NULL).
```

It will autoincrement your id column.

**WebConfig**

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="connstring" connectionString="Data Source="";User ID="";Password= "";Initial Catalog=""" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

**c#**

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstring"].ToString());
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
con.open();
cmd.commandtext="insert into transaction (transactionname) values ('"+TextBox1.Text+"')";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```